# Problems connecting to Exchange 2003 with a Nokia Lumia 800

Tags: email, lumia, exchange

When connecting to an Exchange 2003 server, everything appears to go OK, but on a Noika Lumia, we're only ever able to send a single email - others fail and go to the phone's outbox. Why might this be?

Using a HTC Titan or Radar doesn't have any problems, and our network were only able to say that they'd had the problem themselves, and couldn't solve it either.

**Edit:**

Just tried with a SIM from "another network" and it works fine; looks like we need to beat up our corporate Telco, as this may be their issue

Comment: Did you install all firmware upgrades? There were some issues in the past with exchange 2003 that should be fixed noe. Connect your phone to zune and check for updates (what firmware version do you have now?) [Source](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Nokia-Gearing-Up-for-Lumia-800-Software-Update-235319.shtml)

Comment: This question is very old. Did you solve the case yourself?

Comment: @Vitor I've not got a resolution for it of yet - the closest I can seem to work out is that it's some incompatibility with the Nokia Lumia 800 and Exchange 2003

Comment: Do you have update 8773 already?

Comment: This was with a 81xx build which is carrier specific; We have escalated with BT, who were blaming SSL certificates (even though we were connecting without one)